# Plot multiple lines in one chart using function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a project and I need to plot multiple lines in one chart using **function**, I tried several times but I still don't know what is missing.[image]

I did it without a function and it was successful but using the function is mandatory.   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is an artifact of using Matplotlib's "inline" backend in a notebook, the same code tested in a command line interpreter works as you intended, three lines and a single legend in a single Axes.

To remedy the problem is, fortunately, very easy: just dedent `plt.show`, so that it's executed once, when all the three lines have been placed in a single Axes.

```
def Plot(*cols):
    for c in cols: plt.plot(...)
    plt.legend() ; plt.show()
```

(note that also `plt.legend` can/should be outside of the loop).

---

Post Scriptum

If your function is meant to be executed in a "cell" of a Jupyter notebook, you can just omit completely the `plt.show`, because Jupyter will do that for you when you execute the cell.

---

Post Post Scriptum

[The OP laments continuing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336118/plot-multiple-lines-in-one-chart-using-function/74336352?noredirect=1#comment131235081_74336352), but I cannot reproduce their issues. To this aim, I have defined **two** functions, one with `show` outside the loop and another with `show` inside the loop, and at the bottom you can see what I get using the Jupyter notebook.

I whish good luck to the OP, I'm not going to help them further.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to detent 'plt.show ' , and using command line interpreter as Spyder but it gave me the same result of the three charts.

Comment: Thanks, sir, the problem is solved. The line "plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))" was making the problem and I don't know why. I used 'plt.rc()' and it worked. Thanks again